# Can I avoid tax on sale of home after only 1 year of residence?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax

I'm selling my home just one year after purchasing it (to move into a home with my husband).  I might make as much as $6,000 profit.  I intend to use this money for improvements on the new home.  Will that be considered rolling over to a new home, thereby allowing me to avoid capital gains tax, or is the tax unavoidable?

Comment: Please see this answer, and see if that answers your question for you: http://money.stackexchange.com/a/36283/14835

Comment: Yes USA/Arizona.  Thank you for that link.  I might be able to use an exclusion as my full time job has been reduced to a part time job and I won't be able to afford this home on my own.  I'll be moving in with my soon to be husband, but that's after I sell this home.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Regarding "Will that be considered rolling over to a new home": that part of the tax law ended in the late 1990's